# Vscode fails with Could not load module ‘Database.SQLite.Simple’ while HLS and cabal pass

Tags: haskell, vscode-extensions, cabal, haskell-language-server

I am trying to test writing a simple CRUD app in haskell.
I installed the VSCode Haskell extension and it works for simple files, but for those imports *in Main.hs* I get an error:

```hs
import Database.SQLite.Simple
import Database.SQLite.Simple.FromRow
```

the error:

```
Could not load module ‘Database.SQLite.Simple’
It is a member of the hidden package ‘sqlite-simple-0.4.18.2’.
You can run ‘:set -package sqlite-simple’ to expose it.
(Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
```

my `.cabal` looks like this:

```hs
executable generate-hs
    main-is:          Main.hs

    other-modules:    HtmlGen

    build-depends:    
        base ^>=4.17.2.0,
        sqlite-simple ^>=0.4.18.2,
        scotty,
        aeson,
        time,
        text,
        blaze-html,
        blaze-markup

    hs-source-dirs:   app
    default-language: Haskell2010
```

running `haskell-language-server` passes, `cabal run` sets up a proper scotty instance
the vscode extension is configured to use to look in `~/.ghcup`

what I tried so far:
I tried adding `~/.ghcup` to path and using that, same results
I tried restarting everything, same results
I installed `sqlite-simple` globally via `cabal install --lib sqlite-simple, same results`
looking in `ghc-pkg` but there is no sqlite-simple there

How can I solve this error?
Where should I start debugging?

Any help appreciated

relevant versions:

```
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 9.4.7
cabal-install version 3.6.2.0
compiled using version 3.6.2.0 of the Cabal librar
haskell-language-server version: 2.4.0.0 (GHC: 9.4.7) (PATH: /Users/someone/.ghcup/hls/2.4.0.0/lib/haskell-language-server-2.4.0.0/bin/haskell-language-server-9.4.7)
vscode extension: v2.4.1
```

appending based on comments:
view (in vscode) -> haskell

```
2023-11-12T16:46:22.199302Z | Info | Live bytes: 334.59MB Heap size: 1419.77MB
[Error - 17:47:05] Request textDocument/foldingRange failed.
  Message: codeRange: Rule Failed: GetCodeRange
  Code: -32803 
[Error - 17:47:08] Request textDocument/foldingRange failed.
  Message: codeRange: Rule Failed: GetCodeRange
  Code: -32803
```

current `hie.yaml`

```yaml
cradle:
  cabal:
    component: "exe:generate-hs"

dependencies:
  - sqlite-simple
```

Comment: Can you post the output log of the Haskell extension? Go to View > Output and then select "Haskell (haskell)" from the drop down. Also, is the error in Main.hs or in HtmlGen.hs (or some other file)? You can also try making a `hie.yaml` file with just `cradle: cabal:` as described here: https://github.com/haskell/hie-bios#cabal.

Comment: @Noughtmare I tried those steps, none of them helped, please see ticket if I did something wrong..

Comment: Have you also tried the more minimal `hie.yaml` with only the `cradle:` and `cabal:` lines and nothing else? That should be sufficient unless there is a bug in cabal. And there might be a problem in your current file, you used `lib:generate-hs` but the component is an executable so it should be `exe:generate-hs`.

Comment: @Noughtmare see the updated `hie.yaml`, but the error is still there

Comment: very rare. The `hie.yaml` file could be simpler `cradle:<newline><twospaces>cabal:` (i.e. the first two lines of yours) as simple as that. In vscode go to the hls configuration and set `Haskell > trace > client` to debug. The output should show a cabal error at some point, copy paste that